# Spring boot jersey with mongodb throwing error in connection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I am implementing Jersey in Spring boot and encountered an error.

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

MyRestController.java

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/user/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getUserDataInJson(){
    List<User>userList=userRepository.showAll();
    System.out.println(userList.toString());
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

application.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=local
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

User.java

```
@Document
public class User {
private String name;
private String city;
public User(String name, String city) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
}
public User() {
    super();
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [name=" + name + ", city=" + city + "]";
}
}
```

RestApiApplication.java file

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="org.apedusoft.RestAPI")
public class RestApiApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RestApiApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

UserRepository.java file

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>{
List<User> showAll();

}
```

UserRepositoryImpl.java file

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

// overridded methods

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
public List<User> showAll() {
    List<User> userList=mongoTemplate.findAll(User.class);
    return userList;
}

}
```

gradle.build file

```
dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Unable to get the error, i.e. doesnot know where the error is. Either in mongodb connection with spring boot or somewhere in configuration. What i am trying is to build a RESTful service in spring boot with mongodb as database.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a `UserRepositoryImpl`, delete it, Spring Data Mongo already provides that. Remove the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` you don't use JDBC, but due to the detection of that a `DataSource` is required, which you don't provide, hence it fails.

Comment: @M.Deinum, ok, how i will get the data without userRepositoryImpl... means without writing the query or using mongotempate. i want to return the data on hitting the API.

Comment: Spring Data MongoDB creates the implementation at runtime for you, that is the whole point of Spring Data MongoDB. Also remove the `showAll` and use the default provided `findAll`

Comment: @M.Deinum, Ok working now, Very very thankyou for resolving the issues and clearing my concept on Spring data.

Comment: @M.Deinum, One more thing, i am getting blank list for fetchng data. Can you please tell me how to fetch all data from mongodb using List<User> findAll() method?

Comment: That is a different question... In short that should already return the full list of users, if that doesn't your mongo instance is either empty or you aren't connecting to the mongo instance you think you are connecting to.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I got it. my database was empty. Once i created a user and added document in it. it starts returning data. Thanks